# How can i generate trades at a specific time with pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I tried to write a pinescript strategy that would place buy and sell orders on a paricular date and time and close all trade 30 minutes later. I did this using the timestamp() function. However I keep getting no trades executed and get the following caution message: 'This strategy did not generate orders througout the testing range'. There is enough capital in the stategy settings. I am not sure what the problem is. Below is my code.

```
//@version=5
strategy("News Hedge", overlay=true)

StartDate=input.time(timestamp("3 Dec 2021 14:30"), title="Line Location")
EndDate=input.time(timestamp("3 Dec 2021 15:00"), title="Line Location")

if(StartDate)
    strategy.entry("Entry Long", strategy.long, 100)
    strategy.entry("Entry Short", strategy.long, 100)
    strategy.exit("Exit Long", from_entry="Entry long", qty=100, profit=30)
    strategy.exit("Exit Short", from_entry="Entry Short", qty=100, profit=30)
    strategy.exit("Exit Long", from_entry="Entry long", qty=100, loss=20)
    strategy.exit("Exit Short", from_entry="Entry Short", qty=100, loss=20)

if(EndDate)
    strategy.close_all()
```

I wrote a code. There are no errors from the code as it compiled successfully but there are no executed trades as expected. I tried to reduce the quantity of executed trades and increase initial capital but nothing changed for the codes output.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparision is wrong. `if(StartDate)` will always be `true`. You want to do `if(StartDate == time)`.

Please note that hedging is not supported by Tradingview. You cannot have one long and one short position open at the same time.

Comment: if I use time, it asks for timeframe. Since the strategy is for 30 minutes, how do i add that to the code?

Comment: What do you mean it asks for timeframe?

Comment: I change the if(StartDate) part of the code to if(StartDate == time). Also changed for the end date. However I got an error message: 'No value assigned to the timeframe parameter'

Comment: You must have something else going on. The code compiles as you described. Search for "timeframe" in your code and you should see.

Comment: yes, something is wrong with the code. I am yet to figure it out yet.

Comment: I just figured out my mistake. I did not set the date range of my chart to match the date my code was looking at.

Answer (score 0):

use `if(StartDate >= time)` instead.

This would allow you to verify if the condition is true or not.